# Format of **kwargs in db.Model.query.filter_by()

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a `users` class defined as follows:

```
class users(db.Model):
   name = db.Column('name', db.String(100), primary_key=True)
   password = db.Column('password', db.String(100))
   role = db.Column('role', db.String(100))

   def __init__(self, name: str, password: str, role: str):
      self.name = name
      self.password = password
      self.role = role
```

I'm attempting to create a login form where successful login requires matching usernames with passwords. For this purpose, I tried the following query:

```
user = request.form['Username']
password = request.form['Password']
found_user = users.query.filter_by(name=user, password=password).first()
```

However, this approach didn't work as expected. I received an error stating that the `users` class isn't subscriptable, preventing me from using `[]` to access elements of each row. I'm unsure how to proceed to authenticate users based on matching usernames and passwords. Any guidance on how to properly structure the query or handle authentication in this scenario would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I think I have found the issue:

I have tried out removing off the SQLAlchemy class code and have this instead:

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


app = Flask(__name__)

app.app_context().push()

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']='sqlite:///db.sqlite3'

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS']=False


db = SQLAlchemy(app)



class users(db.Model):


name = db.Column('name',db.String(100),primary_key=True)
password = db.Column('password',db.String(100))
role = db.Column('role',db.String(100))



def __init__(self,name:str,password:str,role:str):

   self.name = name

   self.password = password

   self.role = role



 with app.app_context():

    db.create_all()

 admin = users('Admin','RootRules99','Admin')

 loggedInUsr:users

 db.session.add(admin)

 db.session.commit()

 @app.route('/',methods=['POST','GET'])

 def frontPage():

    if request.method=='POST':

        user = request.form['Username']

        password = request.form['Password']



    
    return user,password









  







 else:

    return render_template('mywebsite.html')
```

with this html webpage:

```
<style>



button
{
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;

    font-size: medium;

    color:black;

    background-color: aliceblue;

    border-style: hidden;

    shape-outside: border-box;

    cursor: default;

    height: 36px;

    width: 144px;

    border-radius: 9px;

    top: 500px;

    left: 680px;

    position: absolute;



    



    

    

    


}
button:hover

{

    background-color: orangered;


}


</style>

<head>

<title>Sign in/Sign up</title>

</head>

<body background="backColorWebsite.png">

<form action="#" method="post">

<input type="text" id="Username" value="Username" style="font- 
family:Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif; background-color: 
aliceblue; position: absolute; top:250px;left:680px; width:144px; 
height:27px; border-radius: 9px; color:gray" maxlength="10"> 
</input>

<input type="password" id="Password" value="Password" style="font- 
family:Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif; background-color: 
aliceblue; position: absolute; top:350px;left:680px; width:144px; 
height:27px; border-radius: 9px; color:gray" maxlength="10"> 
</input>

<button>Sign In</button>


</body>
```

And if I type in the credentials 'Hi' and 'Admin' the website prints out only 'Hi' which is weird because it doesnt take into account the word 'Admin' at all.How should I fix this up?

Comment: *but it didnt work* Are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: Found_user returns NULL even if I give valid credentials.

Comment: Are `request.form['Username']` and `request.form['Password']` returning expected values? Are "Username" and "Password" valid field names? Print the output and go from there.

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: Your `<input>`s must have `name` attributes that match the keys you are using in the form lookups. `<input id="..." name="username"...>`

Answer (score 0):

The form field data is queried using the key that was defined in the name attribute for the input field. You have not defined a name attribute and therefore no data will be received.
In addition, your form element is not closed properly in the HTML code.

```py
from flask import Flask,render_template,request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']='sqlite:///db.sqlite3'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS']=False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(100))

 with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()
    
    admin = User(
        username='Admin',
        password='RootRules99'
    )
    db.session.add(admin)
    db.session.commit()


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']

        print(username, password)

    return render_template('index.html')
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Sign in/Sign up</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        <div>
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" /> 
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" /> 
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Sign In</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```